# Related model can be one of two other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design, relationship

I currently have essentially 3 models at the moment. I have `Project`, `User` and `Contact`.

I'm trying to assign users or contacts as a sort of 'member' to each project. I initially thought that a linking table here would suffice, for example `ProjectMembers` but i'm currently hitting a brick wall in my thought process when it comes to a project member only being allowed to be either a `Contact` or a `User` and whether to handle this via a relationship or by code in the model or the controller by checking which between `user_id` or `contact_id` was not null.

I had a look at polymorphic associations which looked promising, but somehow I ended up with the association backwards (Projects were being entered into the `ProjectMember` table as the type, rather than `User` or `Contact`) and confused myself even more.

The final output I would pretty much like would be simply to have the ability to run something like `Project.first.project_members` and have those members return with the role in that project. It'd be even nicer if I could run `User.first.projects`/`Contact.first.projects` and get those too, but that's something I can figure out down the line.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymorphic association is something that you should go for here. 
**First:** `Project` has a many to many relationship with `User` and `Contact`, hence you need a join table.
**Second:** Since you need to call something like `Project.first.project_members`, you should have a polymorphic association.
For this scenario, you should create a `polymorphic join table`.

Let's say you have the polymorphic table `ProjectMember` with `memberable_id, memberable_type and project_id`  (well I have a hang of [railcasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association?autoplay=true)).

```
class ProjectMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :memberable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :project
end
```

and then in your `User` model,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_members, :as => :memberable
  has_many :projects, through: :project_members
end
```

and in `Contact` model

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :project_members, :as => :memberable
      has_many :projects, through: :project_members
end
```

and in your `Project` model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users, :through => :project_members, :source => :memberable, :source_type => 'User'
   has_many :contacts, :through => :project_members, :source => :memberable, :source_type => 'Contact'
   has_many :project_members

end
```

Now you can call your desired associations, Project.first.project_members, User.first.projects or Contact.first.projects. Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: This is absolutely perfect, thank you! It was quite close to my solution but I was getting hung up on the `Project` model by the looks of things! Thanks again!